# Markdown ordered list are merged into one line

Tags: markdown

Here's how i wrote my markdown file:

[image]

And here's what i got :

[image]

Any help ? Thanks !

=== UPDATE ===
I'm using Jekyll to generate static pages for pages.github.com.

Comment: Actually, the br tag helps ... But i don't know why. Thanks anyway.

Comment: haha do i really need to explain what the <br> tag does ;) Im glad it helped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Any details? What editor/converter are you using? Did you try to insert this Markdown somewhere else like [there](http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/)?

Comment: I'm using Jekyll with its default Markdown parser. I tried your link, it ok there.

Comment: I suggest you add the tag "jekyll" to your question to get more attention.